# extjs - unable to add filters in grid

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

I am trying to do simple thing but somehow its not working out with me, in my grid table i want to add client side filter (in columns), i tried everything and followed the code at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature

my code is,

```
var filtersCfg = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        local: true,
        filters: [{
                type: 'string',
                dataIndex: 'Stage'
            }, {
                type: 'string',
                dataIndex: 'Type'
            }]
    };

//grid
var grid =   Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getElementById("leftPanel"),
        store: myStore,
        height: 300,
        filters : [filtersCfg],
        title: "grid view",

        columns: [
             {
                text: 'App',
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                dataIndex: 'Stage'
            },
            {
                text: 'Stage',
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                dataIndex: 'Type',                    
            }
```

..
..

on clicking columns sort option is seen but there is no filter option

thanks in advance

Comment: try it with `features: [filtersCfg],` instead of `filters : [filtersCfg],`

Comment: with "features", my grid do not render, that means something is happening to it!

Comment: It sure is ;) what does the console say?

Comment: i have been damn fool not to look at console, it complains that feature/filters.js file is missing, but i dont see any such file in entire extjs package!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require additional extensions with `Ext.require`.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext.ux': './ext/ux'
    }
});

Ext.require([
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
]);
```

The FiltersFeature.js is located inside `examples\ux\grid`

Comment: thanks i done that but there is one more GET 404 error coming up, inside extjs-debug-all.js file it is trying to access http://localhost/feature/filters.js

Comment: updated code.. You need to set the path where the ux folder can be found.

Comment: thanks for bearing patience with it, it did not change anything because the file filters.js is nowhere, i found another similar thread http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-140370.html?s=85a1a89e2499ab27c1bc97fe7f392807,  this fellow tells he finally fixed it but he dont know how, i also moved everything under onReady() but result is same. GET 404 error

Comment: You made an error passing the path in "'Ext.ux', './ext/ux'". The "," should be a ":" between object attribute name and its value !

Answer (score 1):

Hi @A1rPun i found that some of my files were corrupted and when i copied fresh ones it worked, i think your answer is perfect, we dont need any feature/filters.js file, only somehow wrong error throwwn in console by extjs

Comment: Should have commented this on my answer so I could get notified :) Hopefully the error is resolved by fixing a typo.